# Can some web sites/applications use "session variables" for users not logged?

Tags: java, php, asp.net

I'd like to know if some web sites or web applications can use 'session variables' (not cookies) to store some data of the navigation when users not logged in are navigating the websites. If answer is yes, what are those cases?

Comment: This is a very broad question.. Something like google analytics will track users who are not online, and users who are. There is also alternatives like awstats.

Comment: depends how your web application logs users out.

Answer (score 2):

Web sites/applications might use [*cookies*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) to store *arbitrary* data on a user's machine (even if the user is not logged in). From the linked Wikipedia entry,

> An HTTP cookie (also called web cookie, Internet cookie, browser cookie or simply cookie, the latter which is not to be confused with the literal definition), is a small piece of data sent from a website and stored in a user's web browser while the user is browsing that website. Every time the user loads the website, the browser sends the cookie back to the server to notify the website of the user's previous activity.<sup>[1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-3)</sup> Cookies were designed to be a reliable mechanism for websites to remember stateful information (such as items in a shopping cart) or to record the user's browsing activity (including clicking particular buttons, logging in, or recording which pages were visited by the user as far back as months or years ago).

Generally, the session id is stored as a **cookie**; but you may store anything you like (just remember that it will be sent **every request**).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes, some websites do collect website traffic data in either Cookies or the service side session. Due to the very large number of variations in methods, this is a question that can't be answered and is open ended.

What specific scenarios you are questioning? An owner of an environmental/non-profit website without user management, my first thought is the analytical data they can capture can provide the common path taken by users to access a particular part of the website. This data can also provide how often portions of the website are accessed.

This data is nowdays captured using a service such as Google Analytics, https://www.google.com/analytics. Analytics captures data on the client side and sends an HTTP request to Analytics and the data can be retrieved for later analysis.